# When a file created with mkstemp() is deleted?

Tags: c, linux, temporary-files

I have a program that calls mkstemp(), writes some stuff with the fd returned and then closes the fd. I want the file to remain until I delete it myself! With something like rm command, or whatever. My question is: will Linux delete this file after close(fd)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> will Linux delete this file after close(fd)?

Not automatically. You need to call `unlink` on the file manually. You can do this immediately after calling `mkstemp` if you don’t need to access the file by name (i.e. via the file system) — it will then be deleted once the descriptor is closed.

Alternatively, if you need to pass the file on to another part of the code (or process) by name, don’t call `unlink` just yet.

Here’s an example workflow:

```
char filename[] = "tempfile-XXXXXX";
int fd;
if ((fd = mkstemp(filename)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed with error %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

unlink(filename);

FILE *fh = fdopen(fd, "w");
fprintf(fh, "It worked!\n");
fclose(fh);
```

`fclose` closes the `FILE*` stream, but also the underlying file descriptor, so we don’t need to explicitly call `close(fd)`.

Necessary headers:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, when a file is created with `tmpfile()`, its directory entry (in the temporary directory) is removed after the creation, so there is only the file descriptor referenced by `open` that leads to the file inodes (in the `/proc/<pid>/fd` directory); once you call `close(fd)`, there are no more reference to the file.

With `mkstemp()` you have to do it manually with `unlink()` right after the creation.

Comment: That's what I thought, but this is not happening here. And, I swear, my OS is ok. And I'm creating the file in the current directory, not /tmp.

Comment: This answer is wrong, mkstemp does not remove the file from the filesystem.

Comment: @nos You're right, I've looked at the wrong method and took wrong deductions.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux Programming Interface book gives best answer to this question. Regard the comments in the code below.

Typically, a temporary file is unlinked (deleted) soon after it is opened, using the unlink() system call (Section 18.3). Thus, we could employ mkstemp() as follows:

```
int fd;
char template[] = "/tmp/somestringXXXXXX";
fd = mkstemp(template);
if (fd == -1)
    errExit("mkstemp");
    printf("Generated filename was: %s\n", template);
    unlink(template);
    /* Name disappears immediately, but the file
    is removed only after close() */
    /* Use file I/O system calls - read(), write(), and so on */
if (close(fd) == -1)
    errExit("close");
```